# Replace printed out text

Tags: swift, command-line, println

I created a command line tool which does some long actions, and I want to notify the user through print statements, like:

```
"10% Done"
"20% Done"
```

on what percentage of the operation is done. If I use println, each progress will be printed into a new line (obviously), but is there a way in swift, that I can replace the last printed text with a new one, so on the console you can read only the actual percentage, not the actual and the ones that printed before?

Comment: Maybe if you can clear the screen so it always prints on the first line? But that has its own disadvantages.

Comment: Would be a nice little functionality

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the output goes to the *Terminal* then you can use the fact that
`\r` (Carriage Return) moves the "cursor"  to the start of the current
line, without advancing to the next line:

```
print("10% done ", terminator: "\r")
print("20% done ", terminator: "\r")
print("100% done")
```

(But note that this does not work in the Xcode debugger console.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried carriage return, but I thought it doesn't work because of the debugger concole, but works perfect in the terminal.

Comment: At least as of Swift 5.5 you also need to add the terminator: "" parameter to print when doing this

Comment: @AndreasBergström: You are completely right. I don't remember how it was in 2015, but that wouldn't have worked for a long time now. Thanks for the notice, I have updated the code.

Comment: @martin-r: actually putting the \r in the string and just passing an empty string to terminator worked, I guess it otherwise appends a \n and print() did not work that way in its first versions?

Comment: @AndreasBergström:  Yes, without an explicit terminator a newline character is appended. There should be no difference between `print("...", terminator: "\r")` and `print("...\r", terminator: "")` but I prefer the former (the CR character *is* the terminator).

Answer (score 8):

Something like this works on the terminal console:

```
import Foundation
for i in 1...10 {
    print("\(i) \r", terminator: "")
    fflush(stdout)
    sleep(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. Swift can't access already printed out strings. But you could create a progressbar where you show the progress. For example like that:

```
|=========               | 40%
```

But you can't change the output of the log, after you've printed it out.

Comment: > But you can't change the output of the log, after you've printed it out.

You can do this, as was shown by others