# Swift print() : Overwrite/Rewrite line in CLI command

Tags: swift, command, command-line-interface, stdout

I am trying to write small cli tool in vanilla swift and currently face the problem that I have to rewrite a line (think of refreshing a progress bar) or ideally multiple lines (think of `htop` that automatically refreshes multiple lines / the whole screen).

Is there any Apple framework that I might be missing that can already handle this ? Is this somehow achievable with the default `print()` command ?

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343701/1801544 ?

Comment: Thanks, but that is single-line only, right ? While that would already solve part of my problem, multi-line is still tricky.

Comment: @Jan feel free to edit the question if you need more support than the linked one gives you.