# How to remove a variable from the field of view

Tags: swift, fieldofview

```
while true {
print ( """
1. Log in
2. Create new user
3. Quit
""")
if let numberString = readLine(), let number = Int(numberString) {
    print("you entered \(number)")
    break
} else {
    print("Try again")
}
}
```

**It is necessary to use the number variable in the future to compare it.
How can it be taken out of sight?**

When I try to make a global var something goes wrong:

```
var numberString: String?
var number: Int?

while true {
print ( """
1. Log in
2. Create new user
3. Quit
""")
if numberString = readLine(), number = Int(numberString) {
    print("you entered \(number)")
    break
} else {
    print("Try again")
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to extract it from the current context?
You could just create a global variable and assign `number` to it.

Comment: but when I do this, an error occurs
(edited the post)

Comment: Or do you mean to clear the terminal / output? One can play with the print-command like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832234/replace-printed-out-text
Please clarify: what is "field of view"?

Comment: `var number = 0`, `if let numberString = readLine(), number = Int(numberString) ?? 0 {`

Comment: @Mick, In the visibility zone {...} I can specify a variable that I cannot use outside {...}

Comment: `if let number` is not a variable declaration, it' a syntax construct. You cannot remove the `let` and use it as a variable assignment in this context. You have to create a new variable, e.g. `var enteredNumber: Int?` but you have to keep using `, let number = Int(numberString)`. Just put the assignment into the `if` block, e.g. `enteredNumber = number`. You might also consider using `guard let` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are creating a command prompt and that choice has no meaning outside your loop there is no need to make it global. You only need to switch the user selection and decide what to do from there. Note that if you try to break from inside the switch you won't exit your loop as I showed to you in your last question. To allow the compiler to know that you want to break the while loop instead of the switch  you need to label your while loop statement, this way you can specify what you want to break when you have a switch inside a loop. Try like this:

```
func getValue() -> Int? {
    guard let line = readLine(), let value = Int(line) else {
        return nil
    }
    return value
}

question: while true {
    print("""
          1. Log in
          2. Create new user
          3. Quit
          """)
    guard let value = getValue() else {
        continue
    }
    switch value {
    case 1:
        print("you have selected number one")
    case 2:
        print("you have selected number two")
    case 3:
        print("Good bye")
        break question
    default:
        print("Try again")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's great! Thanks, but what is the "question" in your code?
"question: while true ..."

Comment: You need to name the while loop to be able to break it inside the switch. If the loop has no name and you call break inside the switch it will just break the switch. You can label it whatever you want.

Comment: Wow, idk about this

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information to go off of here, but I think I can help. In the first script, you are creating a new variable and setting the value for that variable:

```
if let numberString = readLine(), let number = Int(numberString) { ... }
```

In your second script, you have to global variables, but at no point have you provided them a value. What you need to do is provide both global variables (`numberString` and `number`) a value before comparing them. As such, you need to use the == sign to compare different variables/ types. For instance:

```
var numberString: String?
var number: Int?

while true {
    print("""
    1. Log in
    2. Create new user
    3. Quit
    """)
    numberString = readLine()
    number = Int(numberString!)
}
```

You can now compare and or print your global variables...

**Final Code**

```
var numberString: String?
var number: Int?

while true {
    print("""
    1. Log in
    2. Create new user
    3. Quit
    """)
    numberString = readLine()
    number = Int(numberString!)
    
    if number == 1 {
        print("you have selected number one")
    } else if number == 2 {
        print("you have selected number two")
    } else if number == 3 {
        print("you have selected number three")
    } else {
        print("Try again")
    }
}
```

Due to the fact that both variables `numberString` and `number` are now global variables, you can access them in the future if you need to compare them again.

Comment: Force unwrapping numberString is a very bad idea

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for spotting that... `number = Int(numberString) ?? 0`

Comment: @EuanTraynor thank you, but for some reason I get an error:
"Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'"

var numberString: String?
var number: Int?

while true {
    numberString = readLine()
    number = Int(numberString) ?? 0
}

Comment: The string has an optional value. You need to either force unwrap using an `!` or use the coalesce operator `??`to provide a default value if the string cannot be displayed. For your case, I would suggest using the coalesce operator: `numberString = readLine() ?? "some default value here"`